# JPA criteria query for PostgreSQL lateral join

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, join, criteria

I have a PostgreSQL query like following

```
select a.name, v.which, v.val, count(*) as cont
from table a left join lateral
     (values ('ip', ip), ('port', port)
     ) v(which, val)
group by a.name, v.which, v.val
order by cont desc
limit 5;
```

I am trying to use hibernate criteriabuilder to construct this query but don't know what to do for the left join lateral part. Can anybody help ?

So far I have :

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createquery();
Root<table> tableRoot = criteriaQuery.from(table.class);
```

How to specify left join lateral type here ? and group by fields v.which, v.val ?

Comment: How does that join work?

Comment: @K.Nicholas actually it's part of the SQL:1999 standard